# In an online hacking mission, how do I check for people in cars?

Tags: watch-dogs

A guy hacked my game, and I couldn't find him. At the end, it showed me he was in a van. I ran around the van about 5 times during the time I was playing with my scanner out and pointing at it and nothing registered. What was I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

He was lying down in the car.

In your own car missions, you have the option to "hide" in a car.  You need to keep an eye out for driver seats that are lowered and walk up to the car before you can scan him.

Comment: So hiding blocks the scanner and you have to manually inspect then presumably blow up the car or press E?

Comment: It doesn't block the scanner.  It reduces its range.  You don't see them like pedestrians.  You just need to walk closer to the car.